# lodash _.filter timestamp between range of timestamp?

Tags: node.js, lodash

Here my data:

```
[
  {
    "idi": 0,
    "ut": 1479679625,
    "eid": 0,
    "ide": 0
  },
  {
    "idi": 1,
    "ut": 1479679630,
    "eid": 1,
    "ide": 0
  },
  {
    "idi": 2,
    "ut": 1479679650,
    "eid": 0,
    "ide": 1
  },
  {
    "idi": 3,
    "ut": 1479679655,
    "eid": 1,
    "ide": 1
  }
]
```

`ut` is unix timestamp, I need to get all objects between range of 2 ut values. like >= 1479679625 && <= 1479679655 (all objects between first & last object). I use lodash with lowdb and nodejs:

```
const low = require('lowdb');
var _ = require('lodash');

var DB = low('pathDB');
var TIME_QUERY_START_UNIX = 1479679625;
var TIME_QUERY_STOP_UNIX = 1479679655;
var QUERY = _.filter(DB, function(o) { return TIME_QUERY_START_UNIX <= o.ut && o.ut <= TIME_QUERY_STOP_UNIX; });
```

but it throws an

> Cannot read property 'ut' of undefined

How I do a right command?

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste DB value here

Comment: You have to use the built in lowdb lodash query mechanism: `db.get('posts').filter(o => TIME_QUERY_START_UNIX <= o.ut && o.ut <= TIME_QUERY_STOP_UNIX).value();`

Comment: @Gauravjoshi : value of DB is OK, I print on console and it show right data

Comment: @Tholle console throws  Unexpected token =>

Comment: @user2148971Sorry. You might need ES5 syntax: `db.get('posts').filter(function(o) { return TIME_QUERY_START_UNIX <= o.ut && o.ut <= TIME_QUERY_STOP_UNIX; }).value();`

Comment: @Tholle unfortunately it return undefined

Comment: @user2148971 show DB value!

Comment: it show on console a long list something like lowdash function, I thinks this is what you need:LodashWrapper {
  __wrapped__:
   { index:
      [ [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object] ] },
I change an root array in to value of a element like {"index": [..... my old value ....]} and use var DB = low('path').get('index').value(); your code return []

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
_.filter(data, function(item) {
    return _.inRange(
        item.ut, 
        TIME_QUERY_START_UNIX, 
        TIME_QUERY_STOP_UNIX + 1
    );
})
```

check item.eid = 0

```
_.filter(data, function(item) {
    return _.every([
        _.inRange(
            item.ut, 
            TIME_QUERY_START_UNIX, 
            TIME_QUERY_STOP_UNIX + 1
        ),
        item.eid === 0
    ]);
})
```

Comment: Hi, it return undefined

Comment: start:1477958400 stop:1479749400
LodashWrapper {
  __wrapped__:
   [ { idi: 0, ut: 1479679625, eid: 0, ide: 0 },
     { idi: 1, ut: 1479679630, eid: 1, ide: 0 },
     { idi: 2, ut: 1479679650, eid: 0, ide: 1 },
     { idi: 3, ut: 1479679655, eid: 1, ide: 1 },
     { idi: 4, ut: 1479679667, eid: 2, ide: 0 },
     { idi: 5, ut: 1479679674, eid: 0, ide: 2 },
     { idi: 6, ut: 1479679692, eid: 1, ide: 2 },
     { idi: 7, ut: 1479679886, eid: 0, ide: 3 },
     { idi: 8, ut: 1479679895, eid: 0, ide: 4 },
     { idi: 9, ut: 1479731563, eid: 0, ide: 5 },......
 ],

Comment: if I use var DB = jsonfile.readFile and your code, it works, but if I use lowdb, it return undefined

Comment: @user2148971 what kind of data returns from lowdb? publish it at your question!

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, how I find out what kind of data returns from lowdb? I think that library work with lodash library.

Comment: I change an root array into value of element like {"index": [..... my old value ....]} and use var DB = low('path').get('index').value(); and use your code and it works.

Comment: @user2148971 im glad to see it. but, for the future, publish actual input data. And check my answer if it answer for your question

Comment: how if return ut inrange && eid = 0?